# SSL certificate. Can it apply to more domains in future?

Tags: ssl-certificate, csr

What can I do if I have completed a CSR for "domainA.com" but later want it to also apply to "domainB.com"?

I'm assuming there aren't many options once the CA has issued the license, apart from buying an additional SSL cert?

Comment: If you just need a class 1 (privacy, not for payments) you can get a free certificate at http://startssl.com

Comment: They want me to register to use it. I'm guessing I must create an account for the business the cert would be for rather than under my own business name?

Comment: A class1 certificate doesn't contain any account or organisation info. example: https://bfanger.nl/

Comment: Ok it should be sufficient then for my needs. I'm just using it for a Spiceworks help desk portal being remotely accessed by users over SSH. Great news that I can do this for free in future.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm assuming there aren't many options once the CA has issued the
>   license, apart from buying an additional SSL cert?

In the vast majority of circumstances, that is correct.

Depending on the issuer, there's a minute chance that they will let you revoke the old cert and then re-issue on the new domain, but you ought not plan on that being an option.

Answer (score 4):

For a single certificate to apply to multiple domain names, it needs to make use of the Subject Alternative Names field, which will need to be set up at the time that the certificate is generated.

The certificate authorities tend to charge a premium for this, in most cases you'll be better off just getting a second certificate with the other domain name (and a second IP address bound to the server to put it on).